# Dotnetnuke host login redirects to ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: redirect, iis-7, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I've installed the community version of DNN.
then i've started to develop some modules - this worked fine.
then i saw that dnn have AuthenticationServices and wanted to create one for connection to MS CRM.

then i've tried to install this AuthenticationServices and it worked. After that i wasn't able to login to the host anymore. i keep getting the error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

bevor i've started with changes i cloud login with dnndev.me/admin or dnndev.me/host.

dnndev.me/admin get redirected to my custom login page.
And dnndev.me/host gets me an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

is there an easy way to repair this? or do you prefer to reinstall dnn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you try to login into DotNetNuke it will add the login module to the home/start site into the ContentPane.

Unfortunately i changed the template, with one that didn't have the ContentPane. So you can't access with the link `dnndev.me/admin`.

For access via `dnndev.me/host`, I'm not quite sure if it was the same problem.

I solved everything with a new clean install.

and a little hint:
i'm now create a master login page like `masterlogin` and put the `account login` module on it.

now i should be able to login whenever an error occur.